# setInterval queuing up while browser in separate tab

Tags: javascript

How can i stop Javascript from queuing up animations from a setInterval while the page is not the primary tab in view? I've tried clearing the interval on blur of the document but no luck.

Comment: Take a look at this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220785/is-it-possible-to-detect-when-a-user-switches-to-a-different-browser-tab that says that `document.onblur()` might be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus`?

They should dot he trick

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you don't have to care about this, because the browser will automatically increase the interval to 1 second if the tab is in the background. Reference for [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval#Inactive_tabs).

Answer (score 0):

As Martin stated.

Use `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` to pause/unpause the `setinterval` or atleast the contents inside.

For example.

Use `window.onblur` to set `var away = true;`

Then in the `setinterval` you put a `if(!away){...your code here...}` this way the animations will not be triggered when the interval passes.

EDIT

Remember to also put a `window.onfocus` to set `var away = false;`

Comment: I can't get this to work.. i've got window.onblur = clearAnim; function clearAnim() {  var away = true; }

Comment: Ok, please post your Javascript in the question, especially the part with the setinterval then I will help you from there

Comment: It works good enough with document.onblur... its a little sloppy looking for the first second that you come back to the page but then it stops completely - in chrome

Comment: actually no i'm having problems with that now.. It is stopping regardless. apexmarketingconcepts.com - header animation along side of vimeo iframe

Comment: Check the EDIT. Remember you must also alter it when the user is back.