# Detect if browser tab is active or user has switched away

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect if a user is switching to another browser tab?

Currently, I have this:

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function (e) {

    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) { //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                $('.message').html('<div class="alert alert-error">Oops. You navigated away from the ads <a id="start" class="butt green">Resume</a></div>');

                var myDiv = $("#bar");
                myDiv.clearQueue();
                myDiv.stop();
                clearInterval($timer);
                $timer = null;
                break;
            case "focus":
                // do work
                break;
        }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
});
```

But that only works when the user is minimizing the active window.

Comment: In my opinion those Q/A are obsolete. The visibility API allows for much better answers now.

Comment: I agree with dystroy. Those are both over four years old; the web has changed a lot since then. However, oliverbj, you'd be wise to use those as reference for people using older browsers.

Comment: @MattGrande perhaps the updated answer should be posted there as well, then?

Comment: @JanDvorak I've written two comments at both questions.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Now we can use the [visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API).

To deal with the different browser-specific syntaxes, I made this small code :

```
var vis = (function(){
    var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
        hidden: "visibilitychange",
        webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
        mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
        msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
    };
    for (stateKey in keys) {
        if (stateKey in document) {
            eventKey = keys[stateKey];
            break;
        }
    }
    return function(c) {
        if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
        return !document[stateKey];
    }
})();
```

Usage :

```
var visible = vis(); // gives current state

vis(aFunction);      // registers a handler for visibility changes
```

Example :

```
vis(function(){
  document.title = vis() ? 'Visible' : 'Not visible';
});
```

[Demonstration page](http://dystroy.org/demos/vis-en.html)

Comment: thank you, but I cannot out your code in angularjs. it not working

Comment: @Ali.NET I use it on all browsers

Comment: In Firefox 41 (Linux) it doesn't work as desired. If I switch the browser tab, it works ok. If I minimize the browser window it works too. But if I switch to another app, it doesn't work. The ``document.hidden `` property remains ``false`` even if another window is active.

Comment: @pumbo Yes, the visibility API, right now, doesn't make it always possible to know if another application is hiding the browser. I don't think there's currently a way to get that information.

Comment: @DenysSéguret "window focus/blur" method can detect if the user switched to another window

Comment: @pumbo I just checked: if another window goes front and hides the browser, the "blur" event isn't triggered (ubuntu/chromium)

Comment: @DenysSéguret I repeated the test in Firefox 41, Opera 12.16, Chrome 43 and the "blur" event is always triggered on my system (OS Debian 8). Maybe this behaviour is OS specific.

Comment: Is it possible to implement this when close the tab? @DenysSéguret

Comment: @waterkinq What do you mean ? If you want to act on tab closing it's a different matter (and you should avoid it, as it's not reliable and will only be worse).

Comment: @DenysSéguret I want to logout from the site automatically when I close the tab or browser. I mean when I logout the site by closing the tab instead of using logout button, after entering the URL again, I want to logout from the site to force the user to enter username and password again.

Comment: Here it is my question and I tried to use Visible API by looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283638/logout-when-the-user-close-the-tab @DenysSéguret

Comment: Not possible? I was waiting an answer from you @DenysSéguret if it is possible please :/ I have searched it and tried it for a while but still I did not find an answer in Visibility API. Why I can handle switching tabs event but not closing the tab event? If it is not possible, I afraid I will try to find something else to solve my problem :/ If is possible, can you show an example please.

Comment: @waterkinq There's no reliable way to take action on tab/browser closing. It's a design choice (the situation was different 5 years ago). It means you must *never* rely on being notified by the browser of a disconnection, you must handle it properly server side.

Comment: Consider this solution:
 [visibilityState ][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328781/4572425

Comment: hi @Denys Séguret, many thanks for your answer. I have a question on the same, I start a timer when user tabs out and check the timer when user comes back, I start the timer something like this ```      if(vis() == true) {
        currentRequest = Date.now();
        seconds = parseInt((currentRequest-lastRequest)/1000);
      } else {
        lastRequest = Date.now();
      }
``` but see that the time results don't seem to work correctly, i only reports time for one of the tabs correctly. Can you please suggest what can i do to make it work for tabs scenario?

Answer (score 29):

These 3 lines of code **worked for me**

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      document.title = document.hidden ? "I'm away" : "I'm here";
});
```

reference link: [document.hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden)

demo: https://iamsahilralkar.github.io/document-hidden-demo/

Comment: Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event which suggests checking for 'pagehide' as well

Comment: It's now recommended to use [document.visibilityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState) instead of [document.hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden).

Comment: How do I update a local variable in angular with this ? Say I have a local variable, userOnPage, I want to set it to true or False. When I do this.userOnPage = document.hiden, I get the following error: property 'userOnPage' does not exist on type document

Answer (score 9):

If you want to detect whether the tab is **visible** to the user, use `document.visibilityState` to perform the check (a read-only property). Although `document.hidden` works too, as others have written, then [W3C considers it 'historical'](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility-2) and recommends using the former approach.

If you only want to know whether the tab is **active**, use `document.hasFocus()` to perform the check. In this case, the tab could still otherwise be *visible*, but not active (e.g. two parallel view browser windows, where only one is active, both visible).

If you want capture the **change** to the state of visibility (and naturally also the active state in this case), then listen to the `visibilitychange` event from the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

#### Example using all three

```
// Capture change to visibility
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    // Check if tab content is visible
    if (document.visibilityState) { 
        console.log("Tab is visible!") 
    }

    // Check if tab is active
    if (document.hasFocus()) {
        console.log("Tab is active!");
    }
});
```

#### Handling browser compatibilities

You can set up the following checks to cover incompatible browsers.

*Note: Does not include `hasFocus()` as it's [compatible all the way to IE6](https://caniuse.com/?search=hasfocus).*

```
var visibilityState, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.visibilityState !== "undefined") {
    visibilityState = "visibilityState";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} 
else if (typeof document.mozVisibilityState !== "undefined") {
    visibilityState = "mozVisibilityState";
    visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} 
else if (typeof document.msVisibilityState !== "undefined") {
    visibilityState = "msVisibilityState";
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} 
else if (typeof document.webkitVisibilityState !== "undefined") {
    visibilityState = "webkitVisibilityState";
    visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

if (visibilityChange != null && visibilityState != null) {
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
        if (document[visibilityState]) { 
            console.log("Tab is visible!") 
        }
    }, false);
}
```

#### Quick MDN references

- [visibilityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState)
- [hasFocus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus)
- [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event)

Answer (score 7):

**CASE 1**

Just add this `EventListener` in your **constructor**.

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      if (document.hidden) {
        //do whatever you want
        console.log("Hidden");
      }
      else {
        //do whatever you want
        console.log("SHOWN");
      }
});
```

**CASE 2**

See here If you change tab `$(window).blur(function ()` function will call and If you again come to this tab `$(window).focus(function ()` function will call.
**Add this code in your constructor**

```js
$(window).focus(function () {
      //do something
       console.log("You are in this tab");
});

$(window).blur(function () {
      //do something
       console.log("You left this tab");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click here and click outside of this..</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an ES6 multi-browser-solution which I use to determine the tab visibility. I took inspiration from Deny's solution and tailored it to my needs.

```js
const vis = (c) => {
  let self = this
  const browserProps = {
    hidden: "visibilitychange",
    msHidden: "msvisibilitychange",
    webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
    mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
  }
  for (item in browserProps) {
    if (item in document) {
      eventKey = browserProps[item]
      break
    }
  }

  if (c) {
    if (!self._init && !(typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined")) {
      document.addEventListener(eventKey, c)
      self._init = true
      c()
    } 
  }
  return  !document[item] 
}

vis(() => {
  let tabVisibility = vis() ? 'Visible' : 'Not visible';
  console.log(tabVisibility)
})
```