# User presence detection with javascript

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, mouse, detection

(Hello, I have to detect if the user is in front of his computer with my PHP/Javascript website.
I am using mouse and keyboard events but they are only working if the website has the focus.
I would like to detect mouse and keyboard events even if the user is on an other program.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: You cannot see what the user is doing on a website. Perhaps with a browser addon, but not with a webpage

Comment: I think you can't. There was a breach on Internet explorer that allowed you to record keyboard event even if the user was on an other tab. But it was a breach.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, not without writing a plug-in or similar (and getting the user to install it). Purely with client-side HTML, CSS, and JavaScript? No, I don't think you can reliably monitor anything at all when the browser isn't focussed. And I suspect it would have to be a full-on plug-in (as in NSAPI plug-in), I doubt a Firefox add-on or Chrome extension could do it.

This is, of course, a *good thing*. :-) Websites monitoring users when the user isn't using the website? No, thank you! :-)

Comment: Just to get a second opinion in: T.J's right: It's not possible without having the user install something on their system that explicitly monitors / sends this data to your website.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand, I will find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519535/detect-if-browser-tab-is-active-or-user-has-switched-away) pay attention to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519535/detect-if-browser-tab-is-active-or-user-has-switched-away/19519701#19519701) about [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

Hope it helps