# How to make a piece of Javascript work only when the user is on a different tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, title, titlebar

I have the following javascript to make the webpage title change again and again after every five seconds.

```
<script>
        var titleArray = ["TITLE-1","TITLE-2","TITLE-3","TITLE-4"];
        var N = titleArray.length;
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(func,5000);
        function func(){
            if (i == 4) {
                i = 0;
            }
            document.title = titleArray[i];
            i++;
        }

</script>
```

I want it to work only when the user has opened a different tab in order to "attract" him/her back to my site.While he/she is on my site I want this javascript to stop working so the title of the webpage is what I simply write in the title tags.

here is a summary of what I want.

```
<script>
if (the user is not on this tab but has opened and is using a different tab)
{the javascript I have mentioned above};
elce {nothing so the title tags work};
</script>
```

P.S:  Is this a good idea? Got any other suggestions? I just really like thinking out of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if browser tab is active or user has switched away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519535/detect-if-browser-tab-is-active-or-user-has-switched-away)

Comment: Just as an aside - that would be really annoying behaviour

Comment: Have you heard of the Page Visibility API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isActive;

    window.onfocus = function () { 
      isActive = true; 
    }; 

    window.onblur = function () { 
      isActive = false; 
    }; 

    // test
    var titleArray = ["TITLE-1","TITLE-2","TITLE-3","TITLE-4"];
    var N = titleArray.length;
    var i = 0;
    function changeTitle(){
        if (i == 4) {
            i = 0;
        }
        document.title = titleArray[i];
        i++;
    }

    setInterval(function () { 
      if(window.isActive !== true){
        changeTitle();
      }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and efforts but there is still a problem. when I refresh the page I get the title that I have written in the title tags like I want. When I open a different tab your script starts working and the titles start changing which is again what I want. But after that when I go back to the site the script simply pauses and instead of getting the original title(which is between the title tags) I get the last title that showed while I was in another tab.I simply dont get the original tilte back